# how to load html code into c# string?

Tags: c#, html, string

HI, I've got a really seriously question.

I need to send HTML code, so I have to load html into string, and this obvious doesn't work if I can't interpret them well, how can I store it natively?

Thanks for your help

Comment: where are you sending HTML code? how are you sending it? please clarify what you're trying to do

Comment: what are you trying to do? parse HTML in a HttpWebResponse?

Comment: I just want to send html email, so I use a string to store the email contents

Comment: Adding characters to a string should be a piece of cake (it's what strings are for). _How_ does it "obviously" not work? What's happening that's causing it to fail?

Comment: Phew, it's a serious question. Here I was afraid it was going to be a knock-knock joke.

Comment: Just try a small block of html, you will find where the problem is

Comment: Do you mean that you get a compiler error when putting certain characters (such as '"') in the string? Check Marc Gravell's answer, then.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Strings and HTML should be fine. The only complication is escaping, which is made easier using verbatim string literals (@"..."). Then you just double any double-quotes:

```
string body = @"<html><body>
<a href=""foo.bar"" class=""blap"">blip</a>
...
</body></html>";
```

Comment: So @"" is called a verbatim string literal? I'm gonna upvote because up until now I've been saying `use an @(at) sign before the quotes`. Thank you @Marc.

Comment: @marko - yes, that is the official name. Yours works too, though ;)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it just not working with my HTML coding, cos I've tried this, while the double quote still can't be properly interpreted .  Could you try a more complex block of html? Like a whole page? Because the small block works on my computer either.

Comment: @user469652 - I think you need to find an example that doesn't work. As HTML is fine, honestly. If is doesn't work, you've either missed the @ or a "

Comment: Also we need to add double the number of brackets as well. In my case for {{userName}} it should be {{{{userName}}}}

Answer (score 7):

If you html code is in a file you can [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx)

```
string myString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path to the file");
```